# Extract values from input tags inside HTML of an URL

Tags: html, perl

I have some HTML pages. This is sample form data

```
<input type=hidden id=batterystatus value="Charging" >
<input type=hidden id=batterylevel value="80&nbsp;%" >
<input type=hidden id=signalStrength value="4" >
<input type=hidden id=ulCurrentDataRate value="5 Kbps" >
<input type=hidden id=dlCurrentDataRate value="136 Kbps" >
<input type=hidden id=ConnectionTime value="00:15:33:10" >
<input type=hidden id=noOfClient value="2" >
```

How do I extract the `value` attribute that is found in a set of `<input>` tags in the page. For example, I am interested in the data like `Charging`, `5 kbps` or `136 Kbps` etc. in the HTML page.

Once I have retrieved each value, I need to write them to an Excel sheet and compare those values with a set of predefined values stored in another Excel file and prepare a pass-fail report.

**EDIT:** Now I want to do the same from an URL. Here is the piece of code I am using:

```
use Browser::Open qw( open_browser );
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;
use strict;
use warnings;
my $url = 'http://192.168.225.1';
my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(url => $url);
my %tags;
while (my $tag = $parser->get_tag('input')) {
           my $id=$tag->get_attr('id'); # get id attribute value     
           my $value = $tag->get_attr('value'); # get value attribute value
           $tags{$id}=$value;
 }
for (keys %tags){
print "$_ => $tags{$_} \n";
}
```

**Output:**
I run the code, it shows nothing, no errors nothing. It is *not printing anything.*

Comment: What data you want from above input tag? Give some more examples including the work you did?

Comment: Hi arunesh, I have edited the question

Comment: you are still using `$filename` in 7th line please check the script for these silly mistakes.You didn't read the documentation please have a look at it again. If you want to use `url` then change the 7th line as `my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(url => $url);`

Comment: I got the code working now from URL. How do I write **this** procured data on a CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Your Question I assume You are interested in Value attribute of input tags in the whole html page.

For that purpose you can use [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/HTML-TokeParser-Simple-3.16/lib/HTML/TokeParser/Simple.pm) to parse html

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;
my $filename="file.html";
my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new($filename);

my %tags;

while (my $tag = $parser->get_tag('input')) {
           my $id=$tag->get_attr('id'); # get id attribute value     
           my $value = $tag->get_attr('value'); # get value attribute value
           $tags{$id}=$value;
 }
for (keys %tags){
print "$_ => $tags{$_} \n";
}
```

The values are saved in `%tags` hash with `id` as key and `value` as value.

Output:

```
batterystatus => Charging 
dlCurrentDataRate => 136 Kbps 
noOfClient => 2 
ulCurrentDataRate => 5 Kbps 
batterylevel => 80�% 
ConnectionTime => 00:15:33:10 
signalStrength => 4
```

Now you can save the values you need to excel.

Note: If you are new to Perl check [tagwiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info).

Comment: How do I write these values on excel automatically? I don't want to it manually.

Comment: check [this](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.15/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm)

Comment: Now what if there are multiple html files, how do I merge all into one?

Comment: keep those file in directory and iterate over directory  check [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html)

Comment: I was trying to take out the values from an URL by using this piece of code: my $url = 'http://192.168.225.1'; open_browser($url);  but it is throwing error as "Global symbol "$filename" requires explicit package name at start-browser.pl line 9.  Execution of start-browser.pl aborted due to compilation errors. what did I miss? The rest of the code is same as yours.

Comment: I don't know show your entire code and edit your question again.

Answer (score 0):

I like [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) for work like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $html = '<input type=hidden id=batterystatus value="Charging" ><input type=hidden id=batterylevel value="80&nbsp;%" ><input type=hidden id=signalStrength value="4" ><input type=hidden id=ulCurrentDataRate value="5 Kbps" ><input type=hidden id=dlCurrentDataRate value="136 Kbps" ><input type=hidden id=ConnectionTime value="00:15:33:10" ><input type=hidden id=noOfClient value="2" >';

my $doc = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);

foreach (qw[batterystatus ulCurrentDataRate dlCurrentDataRate]) {
  my $node = $doc->look_down(
    _tag => 'input',
    id   => $_,
  );

  say "$_ is ", $node->attr('value');
}
```

Comment: what if it is an html file would I still use my $html = '<input type=hidden id=batterystatus value=.... and this would work? Much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could try reading [the documentation that I linked to](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder). You'll see that as well as the `new_from_content()` constructor that I used, HTML::TreeBuilder also has a `new_from_file()` constructor.